# Can I remove the PIN from windows while keeping my fingerprint and password?

Tags: windows-10, login, fingerprint

I set up a password for my windows 10 user, which is a local (non Microsoft) user. My laptop has a fingerprint reader, so I enabled the fingerprint login. However, windows prompts me to add a PIN as a backup in case my fingerprint doesn't work.

This doesn't seem necessary, since I already have a password I can fall back to. I couldn't save my fingerprints without first setting a PIN, so I decided to set my PIN to be the same as my password (by allowing letters and characters).

Now when I login, I can choose either my password, my PIN, or my fingerprint. Can I remove the PIN part while keeping my fingerprint option?

I suppose I could just remove the password and have my pin be my password, though I don't know if that field allows all the same special characters that a normal password has.

In any case, it seems strange to require a PIN when there is another way to sign-in if the fingerprint doesn't work. Am I missing something?

Comment: I do not do what you are trying to do as it seems to conflict with how Windows works. Nonetheless Go to Settings, Accounts, Signin and PIN can be removed separately (I think) from having Fingerprint. I have not tried this but see if it works.

Comment: When I go to remove the pin, it warns me that fingerprint recognition will stop working.

Answer (score 0):

> Can I remove the PIN from windows while keeping my fingerprint and
> password?

I have confirmed on a test Windows computer with a Fingerprint reader that PIN cannot be removed without removing the Fingerprint.

So you have two options (this works both on Local and Microsoft Accounts):

(1) Just use Password only. That works - no PIN AND no Fingerprint.

(2) Use a PIN. This is required to use also the Fingerprint.

There MUST be a way in if Fingerprint or Faceprint does not work or the recognition hardware fails (can happen). Passwords are now optional and do not need to be used which is why the requirement to combine PIN and Fingerprint (Facial) exists.

Comment: Sounds like an excuse more than a reason. Having a password should discard the need of a PIN. Microsoft should fix this, or remove passwords all the way and call them PINs. Whatever but the current mess.

Comment: It does.  I so said.  See my point 1 above.